# .net class inheritance - overridden function does not get called from its own class

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, class, dependency-properties

I have a class structure like so:

```
Class ReportSection
    ...
End Class

Class ReportContent
     Inhertis ReportSection
     ...
     Public Overridable Function MyFunction() as Boolean
End Class

Class ReportGrouping
     Inhertis ReportContent
     ...
     Public Overrides Function MyFunction() as Boolean
End Class
```

**For Context:** These classes are used to define dependency properties in a wpf project where ReportGrouping is a Dependency Property of ReportContent.  The following is a simplified example of the hierarchy:

```
<kr:ReportContent>
  <kr:ReportContent.Body>
    <kr:ReportGrouping>
      <kr:ReportGrouping.Body>
      </kr:ReportGrouping.Body >
    </kr:ReportGrouping >
  </kr:ReportContent.Body >
</kr:ReportContent >
```

### PROBLEM:

The problem is that if I add the ReportGroup to the ReportContent then the Function in the ReportGroup gets called, even when I am calling the function from within the ReportContent Class.

I need help to make sure the the MyFunction gets called from ReportContent when its called from ReportContent, and from ReportGroup when ReportGroup calls for it.

### EDIT 1:

I tried changing the functions to protected instead of public - same problem

Comment: I was advise against using inheritance to model a hierarchy. Perhaps look at using composition instead.

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by composition

Comment: Model the relationships as properties.  It doesn't look like `ReportContent` is-a `ReportSection`.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: I see - I removed the other content of the classes for example - reportsection has 7 mustoverride porperties and methods as well as reportGroup shares the exact same class structure (numerous Properties) as report content - it just changes two of the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to force it to call the version of the method that is defined by the current class, rather than the derived class, you need to use the [`MyClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3b35kyk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) keyword, for instance:

```
MyClass.MyFunction()
```